# Docker Port Forwarding, Downloading Empty Files

Tags: docker

Im trying to get docker up and running for the first time. I've installed and started a new container and app

```
default  *  virtualbox   Running  tcp://192.168.99.100:2376  v1.12.1
```

Tried running it with two different commands:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 c-docker

docker run -d --name dockerapp c-docker
```

Resulting in:

```
15b763661955        c-docker        "apache2-foreground"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   elegant_mccarthy
1b82dd51b736        c-docker        "apache2-foreground"   51 minutes ago      Up 51 minutes       80/tcp                           dockerapp
```

I also modified `/etc/hosts` > `192.168.99.100 dockerhost` and confirmed Apache is running inside the host:

```
docker exec -it c-docker /bin/bash 
service apache2 status
```

However, when I visit dockerhost:2376 in a browser, it simple downloads empty files. Not sure what is going wrong, but assuming it is something to do with the port forwarding.

Any idea how to get `dockerhost` to resolve for local testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason dockerhost would not resolve is because the port had not been published.

Starting the container image with `docker run -p 8080:80 image-name` did the trick

`-p 8080:80` means "listen on the host's port 8080 and forward those connections to the container's port 80"